# Биос включаеться аномально долго

Tags: железо, bios

Недавно самостоятельно собрал компьютер на основе материнской платы Tuf Gaming B450 PLUS-2. Однако биос запускается аномально медленно - около 40 секунд. Попробовал сначала сбросить настройки до заводских, затем обновить биос до последней версии - результат остался нулевым. Затем попробовал запустить компьютер, отключив от него все устройства (микрофон, наушники, клавиатуру, мышь и неосновные SSD) - результат снова был нулевым. Далее, попробовал очистить оперативную память ластиком и вставить известно работающую оперативную память в разные слоты - также безрезультатно. Теперь у меня нет идей, что ещё можно попробовать. Есть ли другие возможные причины для таких проблем? Могут ли быть какие-либо проблемы с самой материнской платой?

Comment: Что он пишет до или после этой 40 секундной операции?

Comment: Сколько памяти установлено? Тест памяти включен?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Установленно 32GB 3200Mhz 18 16 16, 2 планками по 16, касательно теста памяти, не понимаю о чем идет речь

Comment: @ESkri ничего не пишет, включаю компьютер, вертушки крутяться, а картинки нет, только примерно через 40 секунд появляеться логотип Tuf Gaming и начинаеться загрузка системы

Comment: У меня TUF Gaming не помню какая именно. Долго мучался с настройкой памяти - пришлось обращаться в службу поддержки. Там мне тайминги выставили - сказали, что память моя не тестировалась. Тут мало место и я не дома, позже могу скинуть наш диалог куда нибудь куда скажешь.  Но как я понял плата просто тестирует  память и подбирает настройки процессора. (Я не спец, поэтому могу соврать) Но у меня запуск матери тоже долгий. Хочу отключить Логотип и посмотреть что пишет биос на старте.

Comment: Могу скинуть весь диалог - сюда. Может так будет и лучше

Comment: БИОС на старте компьютера может тестировать память. Надо найти соответствующие установки и поиграть ими  (осторожно, все-таки железо).

Comment: Вторая возможная причина - кривой список загрузочных устройств. Надо его отредактировать так чтобы системный SSD был первым.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в списке загрузочных устройств только основной ссд на котором стоит винда, пробовал еще ставить винду на другой ссд, и загружать с него, а основной ссд вынуть, та же история. По поводу памяти, у меня включен D.O.C.P, пробовал без него, та же история, играть с вольтажем и таймингами желания нет, да и не думаю что это решит проблему, а о каких то других "установках" не имею понятия

Comment: @Ingvar я свою память тестировал у друга, у него она отлично работает и компьютер нормально запускаеться, а в ручной выставке таймингов не вижу смысла

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, проблема оказалась в батарейке CMOS, заменил на новую, биос загружаеться примерно за 6-7 секунд